# JQuery animation speed problem with background

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have 3 big boxes menu.When i move the mouse over 1 box i change the background and works but if move quick the mouse the background doesnt return to the original state.
I think the problem can be the speed of animation.If i use "fast" instead of "slow" in the speed for animation it works but the effect is too fast.

You can better see the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/oterox/nCZmz/)

i'm using this code for each box:

```
   $('#box-orange').hover( function(){        
      $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#E9902C" }, "slow");
   },
   function(){  
        $(this).css('background', 'none');
        $('#home-boxes').css('background-image', 'url(http://dev.thepixellary.es/resources/main_boxes_home.png)');
   });

   $('#box-pink').hover( function(){          
      $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#DD2D77" }, "slow");
   },
   function(){           
        $(this).css('background', 'none');
        $('#home-boxes').css('background-image', 'url(http://dev.thepixellary.es/resources/main_boxes_home.png)');
   });

   $('#box-blue').hover( function(){          
      $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "#29A8DC" }, "slow");
   },
   function(){           
        $(this).css('background', 'none');
        $('#home-boxes').css('background-image', 'url(http://dev.thepixellary.es/resources/main_boxes_home.png)');
   });
```

Is there a way to make the boxes dont get messed up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [my edit](http://jsfiddle.net/nCZmz/2/) for a fix.

I've included a [jQuery Colour plugin](http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/) for smoother colour animations, then on `mouseout` changed the background colour to `transparent`, rather than changing the background to `none`.

The real problem was that if you hovered over the element and then left the element *before the animation was finished*, the `mouseon` animation is still running and so the `mouseout` event of removing the background doesn't become permanent. To remedy this, simply add [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to the element being animated.

Comment: Wooah, this looks awesome! this is what i needed

Comment: Do you think it could be possible animate an image instead of a color? I'd need the boxes to look like http://dev.thepixellary.es/resources/sample.png

Comment: I believe that fading out/in background images is a bit of a pain. Perhaps you could apply the border image below the heading as a transparent PNG background to the heading element, then it would be above the background?

Comment: upps, in chrome works perfect but this doesnt work with firefox/ie9 ?¿?

Comment: Changing the background color.Test your fiddle with firefox or ie9.  I'm using firefox 3.6

Comment: The problem seems to be because there is no initial background colour on the elements. Chrome sets a default, but FF an IE do not.

Comment: do you know can i solve it? I cant have bg color because its an image